# Google Cloud Vision API "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying Google Cloud Vision API (beta) and it is returning "Permission Denied" message. But the "Cloud Vision API" is enabled for the project. Any help is appreciated.

**Error Details from Google APIs Explorer**

```
403 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Project has not activated the vision.googleapis.com API. Please enable the API for project google.com:apisexplorerconsole (#292824132082).",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "details": [
   {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
     {
      "description": "Google developers console API activation",
      "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/292824132082/apiui/api"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by using a CURL request instead of the API explorer or instead of your favorite programming language :

> curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=put_your_browser_secret_key_here
>   --data-binary @**put_your_req.json** > result.json

```
{
"requests":[
{
  "image":{
    "content":"put_your_encoded_base64_image_content"
  },
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
      "maxResults":4
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

as you may already know :

```
base64 your_image > your_encoded_base64_image_content
```

Hope that helps, I don't know why from API explorer there is a limitation.

Comment: It worked with CURL! Thanks Simon. Even the sample program provided by Google [link] (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial) didn't worked. I am not sure if I need to anything specific to make the following code not to show Permission Denied response.

Comment: Sample program was not working since i have not set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Now it is working :)

Comment: @BinoyMathew don't hesitate to share your code using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you enable **Cloud Vision API** for your project.
   Note. It might be not listed by default. You can find it by search.
   [image]
2. Create *Service account key* and download the key in JSON format.
   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork
3. Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
   `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/credentials-key.json`

Comment: This saved me! I had enabled `Vision AI API`, which it turn out it's a completely different thing!

Answer (score 1):

Create google vision api key environment variable:

```
GCV_API_KEY="YOUR_GOOGLE_VISION_API_KEY"
```

Create base64 image variable:

```
BASE64_IMAGE=$( base64 image.jpg )
```

Create json file to query google vision image label detection:

```
echo "{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"content\":\"$BASE64_IMAGE\"},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"LABEL_DETECTION\",\"maxResults\":4}]}]}" > gcv_label_request.json
```

Create json file to query google vision image text detection:

```
echo "{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"content\":\"$BASE64_IMAGE\"},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"TEXT_DETECTION\",\"maxResults\":4}]}]}" > gcv_ocr_request.json
```

Query google vision api to get image labels using curl and store repose in json file:

```
curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=$GCV_API_KEY --data-binary @gcv_label_request.json > gcv_label_response.json
```

Query google vision api to get image text using curl and store repose in json file:

```
curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=$GCV_API_KEY --data-binary @gcv_ocr_request.json > gcv_ocr_response.json
```

Comment: How do i create the key? ... tried https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials > Create Credentials > API KEY but getting PERMISSION_DENIED when trying from postman... I guess postman is not the issue.

Comment: Hi @earthdan , you can check the json response detail. One possible cause could be that the google cloud project, whose api key you are using, has billing disabled.

Answer (score 0):

For GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - please make sure you are pointing to the right credential file. You should ensure the environment variable points to the credentials file you download from the console. 
Otherwise it is going to use the gcloud project and will fail

Comment: even though i pointed it correctly,it is failing. please help. i am using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects and make your project.

After that just enable the service which you want.
Just make sure you save the key to safe location.
This is simple step which can help you to enable the service.

In addition to make your project authenticate and authorize to vision api just follow following step.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html

Answer (score 0):

GCP looks for specific environment variable before making any client,

If you already downloaded the json key file, then simple run this command to save the path of the file to environment variable.

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/file/key.json'