# Why does this command from google's documentation return error 403 despite providing authentication?

Tags: powershell, gcloud, vision-api, powershell-7.2

I am trying to create a product set for google VisionAI. I copied the command used to create a product set(given here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-product#powershell) into powershell 7.2 after setting application credentials. Here is the logs from the terminal:
PS C:\Users[USERNAME]\Desktop\Work\VisionApi> $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users[USERNAME]\Desktop\Work\VisionApi\machinelearning-285617-9fd5155827e0.json"
PS C:\Users[USERNAME]\Desktop\Work\VisionApi> $cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

> > $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }
> >
> > Invoke-WebRequest `-Method POST`
> > -Headers $headers `-ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`
> > -InFile request.json `-Uri "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECTID]/locations/europe-west1/products" | Select-Object -Expand Content Invoke-WebRequest: Line | 4 |  Invoke-WebRequest`
> > |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> > | {
> > "error": {
> > "code": 403,
> > "message": "Permission denied.",
> > "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> > }
> > }
> > Does anybody know what is causing error 403?

Comment: well it looks like you have authenticated just fine but you are not authorized to perform the action. Check that your account has the correct permissions

Comment: The account I did this from is the owner of the google cloud project so it should have all the correct permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Vision API "PERMISSION\_DENIED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532645/google-cloud-vision-api-permission-denied)

Comment: Verify that you are using the correct scopes when logging in. Vision API scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#vision Login scope argument: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login#--scopes

Comment: @JohnHanley, I ran gcloud auth application-default login with the --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision flag. I logged in with the account which owns the google cloud project, and has the owner role in IAM, but still got the error: User [PROJECT OWNER EMAIL] does not have permission to access projects instance [PROJECT:testIamPermissions] Request had insufficient authentication scopes. I ran this command in powershell 7.2, any idea what could be causing the owner account to have insufficient permissions?

Comment: Include the cloud platform scope also.